# Remove type attribute from script added by wp_localize_script

Tags: javascript, validation, wp-localize-script

How can I remove type attributes from all scripts added by wp_localize_script ?

Have the same problem with W3C validation as described here - [Remove type attribute from script and style tags added by WordPress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/287830/remove-type-attribute-from-script-and-style-tags-added-by-wordpress)

But solution described there cannot help with wp_localize_script script's.

--

As a substitute I've used another function [wp_add_inline_script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_add_inline_script/) and solution from question below and helper function to prepare variables.

```
function prepare_var_to_localize_script(string $variable_name, $variable) {
    $var_json_string = json_encode($variable);
    return "var $variable_name = JSON.parse('$var_json_string');";
}

$data = prepare_var_to_localize_script('ajax_obj', array(
   'ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
   'ajax_wp_nonce' => wp_create_nonce()
));

wp_add_inline_script('my-script-id', $data, 'before');
```

Comment: Worth pointing out that these are just *warnings*, not errors. Your site will still validate.

Comment: Did you find a solution?  I'm also trying to resolve this with wp_localize_script().  It doesn't seem to use the script_loader_tag hook.

Comment: @ColinSmillie, added my solution below. Better than nothing.

Comment: @rappongy Ok, I've added a feature request and patch to WP Core here https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/43248 feel free to add feedback.