# What is the point of needing add_theme_support( 'html5') in WordPress 5.x

Tags: themes, add-theme-support

Apparently WordPress 5.x renders HTML5 in search forms, comment forms, comment lists, gallery, etc. I've deleted this support in `functions.php` and HTML5 is alive and kicking. It seems odd that I would need this today, or is this for legacy themes only? Thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You still need to do it, if you want to use HTML5 markup for certain elements. WordPress doesn't have any other way to tell the difference between "legacy" themes and more recent ones, and the old markup is still the default for backwards compatibility reasons. As recently as 5.3 there are still changes being made that require declaring support for `html5` (specifically, [script and style tags](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/353546/39152))

I've just tested it myself, and removing the support declaration for `comment-list` changed the comments from using `<article>` tags to `<div>` tags, and removing support for `comment-form` meant that the newer `type` attribute values were no longer used, so the email field became `type="text"` instead of `type="email"`.

The only reason not declaring support might not have an effect is if your theme is otherwise replacing the default markup in some way. For example, declaring HTML5 support for `search-form` won't do anything if your theme has its own `searchform.php` file.

I haven't confirmed this, but it's also likely that declaring support for `gallery` and `caption` only affect the Classic Editor, and that the markup for galleries and captions in the block editor will be HTML5 by default, since their markup is determined by the blocks.